# How can I modify the md-input-container in angularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on designing a form with angularJS. I am facing this issue from a long time. Whenever I use a text field (md-input-container) and drop down (md-select), this causes a height difference.

When I inspect the code, I find out that the md-input-container has an extra md-error div tag.

[image: Please check this pic]

I want to get rid of this div tag `<div class="md-errors-spacer"></div>`. Any suggestion?

**Thank you**

Comment: Can you just add `.md-errors-spacer { display: none; }` to your css?

Comment: @matmo, Thanks for a quick response but this will hide the div tag on every page. I just want on a few pages where I am not using validation. any idea?

Comment: You could do something like `.hide-validation-error .md-errors-spacer { display: none; }`, and then you would just need to add the class `hide-validation-error` to any of the `<md-input-container>`'s that you know won't need validation.

Comment: @matmo, one question. I am using a class in a md-input-container so how can I use second with it?
`<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>` how can I use hide-validation-error? so that both works

Comment: You can use as many classes as you want on a single element, they just need to be separated by spaces. So you can do `<md-input-container class="md-block hide-validation-errors" flex-gt-sm>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do something like `.hide-validation-error .md-errors-spacer { display: none; }`, and then you would just need to add the class `hide-validation-error` to any of the `<md-input-container>`'s that you know won't need validation.

Answer (score 4):

use this css:

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid) .md-errors-spacer {
    display: none;
}
```